# Why does my PC 'freeze' when the main UI thread freezes?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, user-interface

I've seen many posts about why not using Backgroundworkers causes the UI to freeze and I understand that. But how come when that happens am I not able to move my cursor for a few seconds? I am not sure what a thread is or how it works but surely the work load of one does not affect the responsiveness of another. And surely the Windows 7 cursor does not run on the same thread as my program (4237 or such). Is there a complex, viable reason to this or is it just my PC falling apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Process is an instance of a program executing on the CPU (a process may consist of one or many threads). If a thread hogs the CPU then other processes will 'starve'. That is they will not be allocated enough CPU time to complete. Threads are an interesting topic. For more information search wikipedia for: thread, process, starvation, or deadlocks. If you want to know more pick up a book on Operating System concepts. I have found Operating System Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz particularly helpful (easily available as a pdf).

Comment: 'I not able to move my cursor for a few seconds' - I'm not sure that this is the full story, even on a single-core processor, unless there are multiple, running threads with a higher priority than the UI threads, this should not happen.  'A few seconds' is a long time.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes - I believe that the cursor freeze has little to do with my thread. When I debug in Visual Studio it tells me that the process' number is around 4000-6000 ([6480]Process: MyApplication.vshost.exe) and I recall that this is not normal?